# Flutter project setup

Tags: flutter

I'm having trouble with setting up a flutter project which includes API, database and all the source code. Can someone help me with how to set it up in my windows?

I having all the files but then I have no idea how to import into my visual studio code editor.

Comment: Checkout flutter official link for setup.

Comment: yes, I checkout that but then that is too general and it says how to create a new project but mine I already have a project that just need to set up in my windows. If you any youtube link pls attach here. I need that help badly.

Comment: So you will need to setup environment and path first .

Answer (score 0):

for installation can check the following link

https://youtu.be/UyUdXQuV1_I

**If flutter has been added and pluggin flutter and dart already then ,**

1. **Android Studio**
   do the settings in the settings - language and framework. Make sure the flutter SDK path is correct.
   then do "flutter pub get" on the terminal
2. **VS Code**
   when opening a file, usually in the lower right corner it will automatically ask for pub get